# Remove lines of files in different directories

Tags: python

I'd like to remove the first line and the last second line of files which exits in different sub directories in the same root directory. And the codes as below

```
import fileinput
import sys
import os
path = "./rootDire"
for(dirpath,dirnames,files) in os.walk(path):
    f = open(file,'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f = open(file,'w')
    f.writelines(lines[1:-2])
    f.close()
```

But, when it found the file, the error happened saying no the file which has already been found.

Comment: Can you post the Traceback? Just saying that there is an error is not very helpful if you don't specify what the error is.

Comment: rootDire
['Dire1', 'Dire2', 'Dire3', 'Dire4', 'Dire5']
rootDire/Dire1
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RemoveLines.py", line 13, in <module>
    F = open(file,'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.txt'. In fact, the file *file1.txt* had been found seeming to not be read. Thanks

Comment: you say "f = open(file, 'r')". what is "file" ? BTW "file" is a BIF, you shouldn't overwrite it.

Comment: 1.it founds the file but, it doesn't know the path to the file! 2. you write only file and not files. 3 open(dirpath+filename, "r") i think!!!

Comment: @dugres, regarding `file`, why not? There is `open`, and `file` is no longer BIF in 3.x. So I'd rather say you should just forget that `file` BIF exists.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if it does not work:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import os
path = "./rootDire"
for(dirpath,dirnames,files) in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        f = open(filepath,'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        f = open(filepath,'w')
        f.writelines(lines[1:-2])
        f.close()
```